# How to fade out the end of the last line in a TextView?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

How can we achieve the fade-out effect on the last line of a `TextView`, like in the "WHAT'S NEW" section in the Play Store app?

[image: Screenshot of Play Store app]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That fade effect can be accomplished by subclassing a `TextView` class to intercept its draw, and doing something like what the `View` class does to fade out edges, but only in the last stretch of the final text line.

In this example, we create a unit horizontal linear gradient that goes from transparent to solid black. As we prepare to draw, this unit gradient is scaled to a length calculated as a simple fraction of the `TextView`'s final line length, and then positioned accordingly.

An off-screen buffer is created, and we let the `TextView` draw its content to that. We then draw the fade gradient over it with a transfer mode of `PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT`, which essentially clears the underlying content to a degree relative to the gradient's opacity at a given point. Drawing that buffer back on-screen results in the desired fade, no matter what is in the background.

```java
public class FadingTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    private static final float FADE_LENGTH_FACTOR = .4f;

    private final RectF drawRect = new RectF();
    private final Rect realRect = new Rect();
    private final Path selection = new Path();
    private final Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private final Paint paint = new Paint();
    private final Shader shader =
            new LinearGradient(0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0x00000000, 0xFF000000, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    public FadingTextView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FadingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.textViewStyle);
    }

    public FadingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttribute) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttribute);

        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        // Locals
        final RectF drawBounds = drawRect;
        final Rect realBounds = realRect;
        final Path selectionPath = selection;
        final Layout layout = getLayout();

        // Figure last line index, and text offsets there
        final int lastLineIndex = getLineCount() - 1;
        final int lastLineStart = layout.getLineStart(lastLineIndex);
        final int lastLineEnd = layout.getLineEnd(lastLineIndex);

        // Let the Layout figure a Path that'd cover the last line text
        layout.getSelectionPath(lastLineStart, lastLineEnd, selectionPath);
        // Convert that Path to a RectF, which we can more easily modify
        selectionPath.computeBounds(drawBounds, false);

        // Naive text direction determination; may need refinement
        boolean isRtl =
                layout.getParagraphDirection(lastLineIndex) == Layout.DIR_RIGHT_TO_LEFT;

        // Narrow the bounds to just the fade length
        if (isRtl) {
            drawBounds.right = drawBounds.left + drawBounds.width() * FADE_LENGTH_FACTOR;
        } else {
            drawBounds.left = drawBounds.right - drawBounds.width() * FADE_LENGTH_FACTOR;
        }
        // Adjust for drawables and paddings
        drawBounds.offset(getTotalPaddingLeft(), getTotalPaddingTop());

        // Convert drawing bounds to real bounds to determine
        // if we need to do the fade, or a regular draw
        drawBounds.round(realBounds);
        realBounds.offset(-getScrollX(), -getScrollY());
        boolean needToFade = realBounds.intersects(getTotalPaddingLeft(), getTotalPaddingTop(),
                getWidth() - getTotalPaddingRight(), getHeight() - getTotalPaddingBottom());

        if (needToFade) {
            // Adjust and set the Shader Matrix
            final Matrix shaderMatrix = matrix;
            shaderMatrix.reset();
            shaderMatrix.setScale(drawBounds.width(), 1f);
            if (isRtl) {
                shaderMatrix.postRotate(180f, drawBounds.width() / 2f, 0f);
            }
            shaderMatrix.postTranslate(drawBounds.left, drawBounds.top);
            shader.setLocalMatrix(shaderMatrix);

            // Save, and start drawing to an off-screen buffer
            final int saveCount;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(null, null);
            } else {
                saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(null, null, Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);
            }

            // Let TextView draw itself to the buffer
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            // Draw the fade to the buffer, over the TextView content
            canvas.drawRect(drawBounds, paint);

            // Restore, and draw the buffer back to the Canvas
            canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
        } else {
            // Regular draw
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a drop-in replacement for `TextView`, and you'd use it in your layout similarly.

```xml
<com.example.app.FadingTextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#e2f3eb"
    android:textColor="#0b8043"
    android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
    android:text="@string/umang" />
```

[image: screenshot]

---

Notes:

- The fade length calculation is based on a constant fraction of the final line's text length, here determined by `FADE_LENGTH_FACTOR`. This seems to be the same basic methodology of the Play Store component, as the absolute length of the fade appears to vary with line length. The `FADE_LENGTH_FACTOR` value can be altered as desired.
- `FadingTextView` currently extends `AppCompatTextView`, but it works perfectly well as a plain `TextView`, if you should need that instead. I would think that it will work as a `MaterialTextView` too, though I've not tested that thoroughly.
- This example is geared mainly toward relatively plain use; i.e., as a simple wrapped, static label. Though I've attempted to account for and test every `TextView` setting I could think of that might affect this – e.g., compound drawables, paddings, selectable text, scrolling, text direction and alignment, etc. – I can't guarantee that I've thought of everything.