# How to exactly do Read More in an Android TextView?

Tags: android

Question: How to fade out the end of the last line and append Read More text in a TextView?

**See:**

[image]

Like in this post, I want to append read more text when description is about end and also you can notice that some text are blurry, invisible. I want all those.

I tried some answer, but that are different.

I want like this and **at the end I want to append "Read More"**:
[image]

And I know there is answer in this question:
 [How to fade out the end of the last line in a TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295526/how-to-fade-out-the-end-of-the-last-line-in-a-textview/49299770#49299770)

But that answer is not working for me.

**My purpose is to not expand the texview while clicking on Read More, but instead I'll open new activity.**

Comment: You can find here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099296/set-text-view-ellipsize-and-add-view-more-at-end

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49299770/8956604

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Text View ellipsize and add view more at end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099296/set-text-view-ellipsize-and-add-view-more-at-end)

Comment: @IzhanAli I'm trying

Comment: @IzhanAli I tried that, but I don't want like this. I don't want to expand there, instead I'll create new activity. But I want like this question and I tried, but view is not coming properly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49295526/how-to-fade-out-the-end-of-the-last-line-in-a-textview/49299770#49299770

Comment: @IzhanAli please see updated question.

Comment: @KasımÖzdemir please see updated question.

Comment: @Askar please see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was some problems this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49299770/8956604). I changed it a little bit as like this:

```
public class FadingTextView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

private static final double FADE_LENGTH_FACTOR = 1.5;

private final Shader shader;
private final Matrix matrix;
private final Paint paint;
private final Rect bounds;

public FadingTextView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public FadingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.textViewStyle);
}

public FadingTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttribute) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttribute);

    matrix = new Matrix();
    paint = new Paint();
    bounds = new Rect();
    shader = new LinearGradient(0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0, 0xFF000000, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    paint.setShader(shader);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_OUT));
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // Locals
    final Matrix m = matrix;
    final Rect b = bounds;
    final Layout l = getLayout();

    // Last line index
    final int line = getLineCount() - 1;

    // Determine text direction
    final boolean isRtl = l.getParagraphDirection(line) == Layout.DIR_RIGHT_TO_LEFT;

    // Last line bounds
    getLineBounds(line, b);

    // Adjust end bound to text length
    final int lineStart = l.getLineStart(line);
    final int lineEnd = l.getLineEnd(line);
    final CharSequence text = getText().subSequence(lineStart, lineEnd);
    final int measure = (int) (getPaint().measureText(text, 0, text.length()) + .5f);

    final int fadeLength = (int) (b.width() / FADE_LENGTH_FACTOR);


    // Save the layer
    final int saveCount = canvas.saveLayer(b.left, 0, b.right,
            b.bottom, null,
            Canvas.ALL_SAVE_FLAG);

    // Let TextView draw itself
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // Adjust and set the Shader Matrix
    m.reset();
    m.setScale(fadeLength, 1f);
    if (isRtl) {
        m.postRotate(180f, fadeLength / 2f, 0f);
    }
    m.postTranslate(b.left, 0f);
    shader.setLocalMatrix(matrix);

    // Finally draw the fade
    canvas.drawRect(b, paint);

    canvas.restoreToCount(saveCount);
}
}
```

TextView

```
 <com.example.FadingTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#e2f3eb"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor....."
        android:textColor="#0b8043" />
```

Read More:

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/post_desc"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/post_desc"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:text="Read More"/>
```

FADE_LENGTH_FACTOR = 1

[image]

FADE_LENGTH_FACTOR = 1.5

[image]

Comment: wait,,,let me implement dear

Comment: Okay, I tried your answer, it is better then original question, but my motive is still not completed.  Okay fad out is working, but I want to append Read More like I posted one Quora post image. Exactly I want that. And make sure on the click of read more Ive to open new activity

Comment: You should make your design accordingly. I used two textViews in one FrameLayout.

Comment: I know we can use textview but my problem  is how It should overlap with last line? See my layout here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1WQr4DEuOzm0xS3O_idovVEEi9K-qu8kA

Comment: See in the same link, I added and tested textview, but not working

Comment: I edited my answer. You can copy-paste in RelativeLayout

Comment: Can you please help me for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61843230/how-stick-to-with-adapter-position-while-its-scrolling-in-android

Comment: @ShefaliSingh I commented about that question.